# Initializing array for JSON data advice

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am trying to store data gotton from JSON to an normal string array. The problem is i cant seem to initialize the array size according to the number for JSON data.

For now i declare the array size my own:

```
String[] path= new String[5];
```

This is the JSON part:

class Loadpath extends AsyncTask {

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_imageDB, "GET",params);

        try {
                JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_IMAGEDB); // JSON Array

                // looping through All path
                for (int i = 0; i < productObj.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject image = productObj.getJSONObject(i);
                                            path[i] = image.getString(TAG_PATH);
                }

            } else {
                displayPath.setText("No path");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

So my goal is the array size is gotten from the JSON.length().. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize the mStrings[ ] array size according to the  JSONArray length as:

```
        String[] mStrings;  //<< Declare array as
        mStrings = new String[productObj.length()];  //<<initialize here

        for (int i = 0; i < productObj.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject image = productObj.getJSONObject(i);
            mStrings[i] = image.getString(TAG_PATH);
         }
```

and it is good if you use `ArrayList` instead of String Array as for getting values from Jsonobject as:

```
        ArrayList<String> mStrings=new ArrayList<String>(;
        for (int i = 0; i < productObj.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject image = productObj.getJSONObject(i);

            mStrings.add(image.getString(TAG_PATH));
         }
```

Comment: String[] path= new String[5]; is a global array. Once this array is populated with "path", it will be used by another method.

Comment: @user1850666 : but you are adding path to mStrings array and saying you have path array?

Comment: Opps.. Sorry worng array. Edited it alr.

Comment: Yes. So what do i do next?

Comment: @user1850666 : post your latest code and with full explanation what you exactly looking for because  every thing is fine in my current answer

Comment: ok I converted the arraylist to array and got the results. Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe u can use List instead of String array